# Python in VS2010

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010

i'm trying to work out which language to work with in VS2010, c# or Python.
I understand that there are better ide's for Python out there but i like the VS IDE environment.
If Iron python can do everything CS and VB can do in VS2010 i'll be happy. But can it?

Answer (score 3):

[Python Tools for Visual Studio](http://pytools.codeplex.com/), the Python and IronPython VS extension for VS2010, is still very much alive and is being actively developed. At my previous position, I completed large (1+ year) IronPython projects using PTVS and its debugger, and found it mature enough for serious paid development work.

I used WPF as the GUI layer for these projects, even following the M-V-VM pattern (heavily utilizing `INotifyPropertyChanged` properties and WPF `ICommands`), and it was just as easy as writing in C# - easier, in my opinion, because IronPython code is more concise and requires much less boilerplate.

I can provide some more info on my experience with development in IronPython and WPF if you like - just ask me or leave a comment.

Comment: Whar gui designer did you use? Does ms maintain the software tou describe?

Comment: Visual Studio's integrated WPF designer was more than enough for 90% of my UI design, and for advanced stuff like style/template editing I used Expression Studio 4 to open the xaml files. MS has open-sourced IronPython, and PTVS has always been open source. Both projects are kept up to date by a group of contributors (shoutout to [@Dino Viehland](http://stackoverflow.com/users/114000/dino-viehland))

Comment: Are you saying that you can use the designers in as integrated as fashion as you can for C# and CB?

Comment: Yes; there some limitations that are inherent to using a dynamic language such as IronPython. For example, say you have some text element that's bound to a property on your IronPython ViewModel; the value obviously won't show up in the designer, because your IronPython code hasn't been run yet.

Comment: Ultimately this largely comes down to opinions. My instincts are that IronPython will fade away. You are more optimistic. Without a time machine we can't know. I hope I'm wrong because it's fabulous technology.

Comment: Yeah, I think MS should make it a top-tier .NET language, since it really does combine the best of both worlds, Python and .NET, allowing you to use libraries from both. But then, MS has a history of dropping support from promising technologies. It's fortunate that IronPython still has a highly skilled community keeping it up to date even though MS isn't paying people to do it anymore.

Comment: Now you seem to be agreeing with me and the sentiments in my answer!!

Answer (score 0):

> If Iron python can do everything C# and VB can do in VS2010 i'll be happy. But can it?

No, C# and VB, and to a lesser extent F#, are the primary languages for Visual Studio. Microsoft support for IronPython has been dropped and it seems to be stagnating.

If you are just writing console based code then you may be OK with IronPython, but if you are doing any GUI work then I would not recommend it.

Even then, the fact that the language no longer has MS backing leaves me with a bad feeling. I would not invest time and effort into writing IronPython code because I suspect that it will become a dead end.

Comment: cheers for that, so this talk of fully integrated iron python coding is dead huh?

Comment: In my opinion, it was never really alive.

Comment: Not true; IronPython and its IDE support are still being actively developed and supported. See my answer.